# cannot properly return askdirectory() value

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm making a project in which I have to implement a browse folder button and further put that file path into another function. I made a function that asks me for the directory and it returns the path. but the problem I am facing is whenever I'm calling the function the window also opens for me to select the path again. how can I store the path in a variable without triggering the askdirectory() function?

Here is my code :

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
import tkinter as tk

full = tk.Tk()
full.geometry("400x200")
name = Label(full, text = "Enter Image Directory").place(x = 5,y = 30)

def askDir():
    file = filedialog.askdirectory()
    return file

dir = askDir() # doing this will always trigger the askdirectory function.
print (dir) 

Button(full,text = "Browse",command = lambda:askDir(),padx=50).place(x = 140, y = 30) 
# i only want the function to be triggered when i press the button


full.mainloop()
```

My expectation is when ill press the button then only ill get the select directory prompt and after selecting the path should get stored in a variable that I can use in another function.

Comment: Change `dir = askDir()` to `dir = None` and update `dir` inside `askDir()`, note that you need to add `global dir` at the beginning of `askDir()`.

Comment: Plain and simple: functions called from events cannot return items. Or more correctly, whatever they return is ignored. This is a fundamental feature of pretty much all GUI toolkits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use code below:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
import tkinter as tk

full = tk.Tk()
full.geometry("400x200")
name = Label(full, text = "Enter Image Directory").place(x = 5,y = 30)
dir=None
def askDir():
    global dir
    dir = filedialog.askdirectory()
    test()

def test():
    print(dir)

Button(full,text = "Browse",command = lambda:askDir(),padx=50).place(x = 140, y = 30) 

full.mainloop()
```

just define (dir) as a global variable.
now you can use (dir) in any function that you want.

have fun :)